# Normal check interval and re try check interval doesnot work in nagios

Tags: nagios

I have configured nagios in my environment and i have used the following setting for a service which monitors the disk space for every 10 min ,

```
Normal check interval =10 min
retry check interval = 1 min
Maximum attempts =2
```

But accoring to this values i should recieve my first alert after 10 min and then from there for every 1 min. But in my case i am recieving my first alert and then next alert comes to me after 20 min.  Can some one help me in fixing this.

Comment: No, you are wrong. You should get alerts after 11 mins, not 10.

Could you post your service object definition?

Tore

Comment: FYI, checking disk space every 10 mins is just silly.

Comment: Consider accepting an answer if one of the answers solved it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Check retries has nothing to do with the interval notifications are sent.
Use this parameter in your service definition:

notification_interval

Answer (score 1):

check if you have is_volatile set to 0
if not then set it to zero and your notification interval will kick in and start working.

Answer (score -1):

How many servers are you monitoring? 
Because I am afraid that you have 2 servers being monitored. The check interval does like a 'round' of checks for all servers, so if you have, for example, 3 servers, first one gets checked at 0:10, second one gets checked at 0:20 and third one gets checked at 0:30. So the first one is going to get checked again at 0:40.

Also the retry check interval is the amount of time Nagios waits until try to check again the same server if it fails or can not connect when doing the check.

Comment: Where did you get the idea about this round?  I have never heard of that.. Also when I look at my service checks via the web gui, last check and next scheduled check are exactly check_interval minutes apart regardless of how many hosts have that service.

Comment: I have configured Nagios3 for monitoring 2 webservers and the gateway host. When I set it up once to get checked each 10 min, Nagios didn't check all at the same time, leaving 10 min between each host check. Later I changed the check_interval value to 5 min, as I have it now, and still have the same behaviour. Maybe I am missing some configuration detail which I don't know, but I got this idea from user experience.

Comment: Dez, your understanding of Nagios scheduling system is all wrong.